# Dynamic Site Templates

Tags: site-template

Let's say I have Template A with 20 libraries. What I want is, user can 'de-select' some of these libraries so that when the site is created, it doesn't have those libraries.

Currently, only way I'm thinking of doing it is through Custom Form and Custom Workflow since I think the OOTB Site Template feature sharepoint provides does not allow the dynamically changing libraries.

Is there an easier way that I am missing?

Thank you!

Edit: I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is deploy a "basic" template without the libraries enabled and enable users to add them through features (web scoped). There are also 3rd party tools which support self service site creation with customization through features (so you can choose which features will be enabled when the templates is used to create a site).